# Sending Firebase Storage from Flutter Web Blob

Tags: flutter, web, blob, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload image to Firebase storage from an image blob in Flutter Web. I have blob link as "blob:http://localhost:62295/819d9312-6bf3-4e68-864b-9591d8266008". What is the trick for **blob:http** url? In what format or encoding the image is saved? I tried downloading image as if it is a remote image then tried to upload with firebase storage but can't obtain the original image in the end. Is there a way to obtain image as demanded format from **blob:http** link and upload to firebase via html.Blob or UInt8List data? Thanks in advance.